# Display selected items in sequence using JComboBox TableCellEditor

Tags: java, swing

I am displaying a table with combo box editor in sports and arts columns. The items that are selected are added to the list even if they are selected in random manner. My problem is to map the contents in firstname column with sports column and arts column correctly. My code, based on [`TableRenderDemo`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#eg), is given here.

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995, 2008, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 *   - Neither the name of Oracle or the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
 * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */ 

/*
 * TableRenderDemo.java requires no other files.
 */

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class TableRenderDemo extends JPanel {
    private boolean DEBUG = false;
    static LinkedList<String> helpStringFirst = new  LinkedList<String>();
    static LinkedList<String> helpStringSecond = new  LinkedList<String>();
 static LinkedList<String> arts = new LinkedList<String>();
 Object[][] data = {
            {"Kathy", "Smith", "Snowboarding", "PencilArt", new Boolean(false)},
            {"John", "Doe", "Rowing", "Drawing", new Boolean(true)},
            {"Sue", "Black","Knitting", "Yoga", new Boolean(false)},
            {"Jane", "White","Speed reading","Music", new Boolean(true)},
            {"Joe", "Brown", "Pool", "Dance", new Boolean(false)}
            };
    public TableRenderDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1,0));

        String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
                                "Last Name",
                                "Sports",
                                "Arts",
                                "Vegetarian"};


        final Object[] longValues = {"Jane", "Kathy",
              "None of the above",
              new Integer(20), Boolean.TRUE};

        final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(1000, 200));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

             setUpSportColumn(table, table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2));
             setUpArtsColumn(table, table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3));

        add(scrollPane);

    }

  public void setUpSportColumn(JTable table,
                               TableColumn sportColumn) {
      //Set up the editor for the sport cells.
      final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
      comboBox.addItem("Snowboarding");
      comboBox.addItem("Rowing");
      comboBox.addItem("Knitting");
      comboBox.addItem("Speed reading");
      comboBox.addItem("Pool");
      comboBox.addItem("None of the above");
      sportColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox));

      //Set up tool tips for the sport cells.
      DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer =
              new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
      renderer.setToolTipText("Click for combo box");
      sportColumn.setCellRenderer(renderer);
      comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

          @Override
          public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {                     
                  if ((e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) ) {                      
                      String str = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
                      System.out.println("str>>:"+str);  
                      setLabelText(str);
                  }                         
          }
      });

  }
  public void setUpArtsColumn(JTable table,
          TableColumn artColumn) {
    //Set up the editor for the sport cells.
    final JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox();
    comboBox1.addItem("Pencilsketch");
    comboBox1.addItem("Drawing");
    comboBox1.addItem("music");
    comboBox1.addItem("Dance");
    comboBox1.addItem("Yoga");
    comboBox1.addItem("None of the above");
    artColumn.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox1));  
    //Set up tool tips for the sport cells.
    DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer =
    new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    renderer.setToolTipText("Click for combo box");
    artColumn.setCellRenderer(renderer);
    comboBox1.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

      @Override
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
          if ((e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)) {

              String str1 = comboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
             System.out.println("str:"+str1);
              setLabelText1(str1);
          }
      }
  });   
  }
  private static void setLabelText(String str1) {

      helpStringFirst.add(str1);
      System.out.println("helpStringFirst:"+helpStringFirst);
  }
  private static void setLabelText1(String str2) {

      helpStringSecond.add(str2);
      System.out.println("helpStringSecond:"+helpStringSecond);  
  }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleTableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Create and set up the content pane.
        TableRenderDemo newContentPane = new TableRenderDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.          
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please cite the original and show how your code differs.

Comment: you can get an idea by simply running that program.

Comment: Even if i select the items in sports column randomly ie selected (1,2) first and then (2,2) then (0,2) i want to get the values sequentially that is (0,0) maps to (0,2),(1,0) maps to (1,2) ,(2,0) maps to (2,2) and so on..

Comment: Cited. I see you've added a second `TableCellEditor`, `comboBox1`, but I don't understand the mapping.